# character array handling in c (copy pointer to character array)

Tags: c

I have a pointer with type `const char* FunctionName` , How can I put that into a `payload` of type `char payload[100]` without any warning or errors? Also the `payload[0]` is filled with character value already, so the space starting from `payload[1]`

update:

I tried like this `strcpy((&payload[1]),FunctionName); is working now.

But Ihave one more question, how can accomodate the pointer(FunctionName) into the `payload[1]` ratherthan copying the entire string? through any assignment statement?

/R

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
strncpy(&payload[1], FunctionName, 98);
payload[99] = '\0';
```

should be safe in the case that FunctionName has more than 98 characters before the NULL terminator.

Comment: what happens if FunctionName has less than 98 characters? I mean to say where should the NULL terminator be placed?

Comment: `strncpy` will pad the buffer with NULLs up to 98 if FunctionName is shorter than that, so you don't need to do anything different.

Comment: Great. It worked.. Don't you think, if the padding is done automatically, then the `payload[99] = '\0';` statement isn't required?

Comment: No, the last line is required if the `FunctionName` has >= 98 characters. Rather than performing an expensive `strlen()` on `FunctionName` first, just append the NULL. It's true it's not needed if `FunctionName` is *always* less than 98 characters but this is just good defensive coding practice. If you leave it out, someone will inevitably come along and call your code with a `FunctionName` longer than you were expecting some time in the future.

Comment: I mean to say, if that statement isn't there, and FunctionName is given a longer value than 98, how would the compiler react? Basically, what are the after implications?

Comment: I tried like this strcpy(payload[1],FunctionName); and getting the error
passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @Sandip Agarwal: The compiler would not care. At run time, you would write over the end of the `payload` array and trash whatever was in memory after that. Then all bets are off.

Comment: @Renjith G: you need to use `&payload[1]` (the address of element 1 of `payload`) as the first argument - you are using the content of element 1 of `payload` with your statement. But `strcpy` (rather than `strncpy`) is not safe as I have explained.

Comment: Thanks Vicky.Now it resolved.Biut how can I accomodate the pointer(FunctionName) into the payload[1] ratherthan copying the entire string? through any assignment statement?

Comment: @Renjith G: I'm not quite clear what you mean. Suppose the address of `FunctionName` is 0x01020304, do you want `payload[1]` to contain 0x01, `payload[2]` to contain 0x02, `payload[3]` to contain 0x03, and `payload[4]` to contain 0x04? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Vicky: I have to move the address 0x01020304 to payload starting from payload[1], so that I can get the data upon receiving that payload some other places.That means to reduce the overhead of sending the full string , just send the pointer to that string only

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3849/discussion-between-renjith-g-and-vicky)